# .BAT файл переключения языка

Tags: bat

Как через .bat файл сменить горячие клавиши переключения языка на ALT+SHIFT?

Comment: ```reg add "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\toggle" /v Hotkey /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f```

Comment: @gregzakharov Пишите как ответ. Задачу решает.

Answer (score 3):

```
reg add "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\toggle" /v Hotkey /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f
```